# Update multi times current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I want to update multi times current location.
In my viewDidload method:

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0f;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In my didUpdateToLocation method I have log newlocation.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Updated Location : lat--%f long--%f",latitude,longitude);
}
```

But it only log one more.

I want to it update current multi times.

====Updated my code:

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation{
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
//    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
//    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
//    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
        // If the event is recent, do something with it.
        longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
        latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
        [_lbllongtitude setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+.6f",longitude]];
        [_lbllatitude setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+.6f",latitude]];
//    }
    [self getLocationMapView];
}
```

It is not auto update current location,

Please help me!

Comment: Unrelated but never do a check for the iOS version. Check to see if the class or method exists.

Comment: That delegate method is deprecated too - Use `didUpdateLocations:`  Have you moved more than a kilometre from the initial location?

Comment: Use -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations method.
Paulw11 can you help me about code this my problem.

Comment: You can use kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters for desiredAccuracy, It will update your location when your device moved out of 10 meters. At every 10 meter distance, It will update.

Comment: tks mrunal thanki.
I will try later.

Comment: If it is periodic update use timer to get location by calling startUpdatingLocation, in delegate stop it by using stopUpdatingLocation.
If it location updates needed for certain location moved use distance filters.

Answer (score 0):

you can update multi time location by changing property.

here is full source code :

in your .h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnGetLocation;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblsetLongitude, *lblsetLattitude, *lblsetAddress;
-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender;
@end
```

in your .m fille:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationmanager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize lblsetAddress,lblsetLattitude,lblsetLongitude;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationmanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
   // placemark=[[CLPlacemark alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender
{
    locationmanager.delegate=self;
    locationmanager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Failed to get Location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *currentlocation=newLocation;

    if (currentlocation!=nil) {
        self.lblsetLattitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentlocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.lblsetLongitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentlocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentlocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            lblsetAddress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
@end
```

by changing property you can get multi time updated location.

property like:

```
kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
```